# Hiding element with if statement (pure Javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

Im trying to hide h3 headers, but the else statement doesnt seem to work. How can I modify this code so its cleaner and working? The "mark" is my custom dynamic tag that is adds to the page when you type something to the search bar. And thats exactly when I want to hide the all the h3. But once the search bar is empty all h3 headers should become visible.

```
var sectionHeader = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
var keyword = document.getElementsByTagName("mark");

if(typeof(keyword) != 'undefined' && keyword != null){
    console.log("h3 headers are hidden");
    for (i = 0; i < sectionHeader.length; i ++) {
        sectionHeader[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
} else {
    console.log("h3 headers are visible");
    for (i = 0; i < sectionHeader.length; i ++) {
        sectionHeader[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` never returns `undefined` or `null`, it always returns a `NodeList`.  If there are no `mark` elements, the NodeList will be empty. So test its length.

```
if (keyword.length > 0){
    console.log("h3 headers are hidden");
    for (i = 0; i < sectionHeader.length; i ++) {
        sectionHeader[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
} else {
    console.log("h3 headers are visible");
    for (i = 0; i < sectionHeader.length; i ++) {
        sectionHeader[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```